# vector<int>::iterator versus list<int>::iterator keys in std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

Why can a map of vector::iterator to int be defined but a map of list::iterator to int cannot?

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

    vector<int> v(begin(ia), end(ia));
    auto it1 = find(begin(v), end(v), 4);
    map< vector<int>::const_iterator, int > m1;
    m1.insert(map<vector<int>::const_iterator, int>::value_type(it1,*it1));

    list<int> l(begin(ia), end(ia));
    auto it2 = find(begin(l), end(l),5);
    map< list<int>::const_iterator, int> m2;
    m2.insert(map<list<int>::const_iterator, int>::value_type(it2,*it2)); //doesn't compile

}
```

---

> Error 1   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Error 1 error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: That should be in the question (so I've added it). Out of interest, was that on the `m2.insert` line, or the _declaration_ of m2?

Comment: @Useless: that could easily be on the `insert` line, since until then, the compiler doesn't instantiate any code that needs the comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` requires that the key be comparable, either with `<`, or a provided comparator.

Conceptually, random-access iterators are comparable, but bidirectional iterators aren't. `std::vector` iterators are random access, and `std::list` iterators are bidirectional.

So, your list iterator doesn't satisfy the comparable requirement of a `std::map` key type. If you provide a comparator which *can* usefully decide which `std::list::const_iterator` should come before another, you can pass it to the map and this will work. Rough sketch:

```
struct ListIterCmp {
    bool operator() (list<int>::const_iterator a, list<int>::const_iterator b)
    {
        // how?
    }
};
map< list<int>::const_iterator, int, ListIterCmp> m2;
// this should work now...
```

---

The [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) documentation covers everything I used to use the old [SGI](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html) docs for, and is still  updated. See that both describe `a<b` for the RandomAccessIterator, and not for the BidirectionalIterator concept.

Comment: Indeed, as suspected. Thanks for the link listing all allowed expressions. bidirectional iterators don't support <,>,<=,>= of course as they can be incremented in either direction and thus violate strict weak ordering in key types.

Comment: This [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) document seems slightly better organized.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare iterators from `std::list<T>` for any T. Indeed, `std::vector<T>::iterator` is only comparable if both iterators in question come from the same vector.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot compare `std::list` iterators is that it would be grossly inefficient - you would have to walk from one of them possibly to the end of the whole list just to find the other element is not after it. That would be `O(N)` complexity, which we don't want for simple operations like `<`.

I cannot suggest a replacement, as I don't know what you need it for. Because addresses of `std::list`'s elements are stable, you could use the addresses as keys for a `map`. But I fail to see how this would be useful.